# Trouble closing img tags in Javascript – using strict xhtml DTD

Tags: javascript, image, tags, xhtml-1.0-strict

I am using a Javascript called Niceforms.js which makes HTML forms looks pretty. It works fine under the xHTML Transitional Doctype, but I need to build my site using Strict xHTML.

It has a few problems rendering under Strict and I'm fairly sure it's because it isn't putting the trailing slash in a few `<img>` elements so that they are `<img ... />`. Here is the code that is creating the `<img>` tags. How can I get it to output the trailing slash?

```
el.topLeft = document.createElement('img');
el.topLeft.src = imagesPath + "0.png";
el.topLeft.className = "NFTextareaTopLeft";
```

I hope this is enough of the code to help. I am not very experienced with Javascript.

The whole script can be downloaded here if it helps... 
http://www.emblematiq.com/lab/niceforms/download/

Thank you in advance!
Pete

Comment: `createElement` directly influences the DOM. What do you use to look at the generated HTML?

Comment: I'm using Coda (on Mac) to inspect the elements and that's where I can see it outputting img tags in old, unclosed, HTML style.

Comment: Ok, that question has prompted me to look at it in Firebug. In Firebug it is showing the trailing slash. I guess that means my initial thought on the bug was not unclosed tags. Damn!

Comment: What are the actual manifest problems you're seeing? In other words, what's going wrong in the visible layout of your pages? What you do to the DOM *after* the page source has been parsed doesn't really have much to do with which DTD guided the parser.

Comment: I think I'm getting there on most of the bugs. Still a few issues with IE (only checked IE8 so far).

These were the problems I was facing... 

This is the script's demo page with Transitional Doctype:
http://www.pad-dev.co.uk/niceforms/transitional.html

This is the script's demo page with Strict Doctype:
http://www.pad-dev.co.uk/niceforms/strict.html

Look half way down at the textarea, file upload and multiple select. Some of the framing graphics have shifted.